# Postman Newman not able to parse JSON in CSV file

Tags: postman, newman

First line shows how the data is saved in Excel. 
Second line shows how same data is stored in CSV file.

```
BOOKID123,None,{"present":true,"ID":{"1234":{"present":true,"answer":{"code":23,"message":"Ready to publish"}}}}

BOOKID123,None,"{""present"":true""ID"":{""1234"":{""present"":true","answer"":{""code"":23","message"":""Ready to publish""}}}}"
```

Postman is able to parse the JSON shown in third column of CSV file.
But Newman command line cannot parse the JSON.

Following are the errors:

```
Invalid closing quote at line 2; found "\"" instead of delimiter ","
```

So I escaped all the double quotes. Then the next error was:

```
Number of columns on line 2 does not match header
```

which is due to the commas in the JSON.

Is the only solution to use JSON file instead of CSV file? It was easier adding data in Excel hence I chose the CSV route.

Comment: Did you check what newman expects as delimiter and wrapping characters? Personally, I find it horrible to read json inside a csv, using json and transforming it on the server to the required format seems to be a much more future proof way

Answer (score 0):

In postman [support forum](https://community.getpostman.com/t/how-can-i-escape-a-comma-in-data-csv-file/) I've recieved the solution to put commas in qoutas: Canada"," Toronto. But it works only in runner. Newman does not accept such data fields in CSV. The only decision I suggest is to escape commas in json file for newman:

```
"username": "abhinav,",
```

forum quote

> I was putting quotes round the entire string which does not work
>   e.g. “data2,with comma”
>   putting quotes round the comma only does work
>   e.g. data2","with comma

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21742652)

Comment: My original post contains the sample solution from the link